# Finding a disabled eth0 using lsmod

Tags: networking, lenovo, ethernet

I have a lenovo x201. I'm trying to install ethernet on my ubuntu.

When I use `ifconfig` (or `ifconfig -a`), I can't find it. Which means that it is not installed.

Which module is the eth0?

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
wacom_w8001            13110  0 
joydev                 17693  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32530  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    62317  1 
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
bluetooth             180113  10 rfcomm,bnep
arc4                   12529  2 
snd_hda_intel          33719  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3                                               snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17764  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97275  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61929  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
thinkpad_acpi          81819  0 
nvram                  14413  1 thinkpad_acpi
wmi                    19256  0 
tpm_tis                18804  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
snd                    79041  17         snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,s    nd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device,thinkpad_acpi
iwlwifi               401033  0 
i915                  478556  8 
mac80211              506862  1 iwlwifi
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915
drm                   241971  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
serport                12936  1 
psmouse                97519  0 
cfg80211              205774  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
serio_raw              13211  0 
uvcvideo               72627  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
mei                    41616  0 
intel_ips              18174  0 
lp                     17799  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
video                  19651  1 i915
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
e1000e                156873  0
```

Comment: The ethernet driver in your lsmod is e1000e. It is for various Intel ethernet devices and is often found in Lenovo laptops. Doesn't your ethernet connect? What are your symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ethernet module appeared on the last line:

```
e1000e                156873  0
```

Modinfo:

```
modinfo e1000e|grep ^desc
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
```

If it was properly loaded, check with:

```
dmesg|grep e1000e
```